# Calculate order based on coordinates of x and y

Tags: coordinate-systems

I would like to map coordinates $(x,y)$ to a particular order ID, which will help me track when the coordinates changes.

I need a formula which gets a specific ID based on coordinates.

Here are a few examples for coordinates:

- 00-1
- 10-2
- 01-3
- 11-4
- 02-5
- 12-6
- 03-7
- 13-8
- 04-9
- 14-10

Comment: why not just 2 hexes

Comment: Could you elaborate more, What does hexes mean ? I need a formula wherin i pass the coordinates and I receive the order Number

Answer (score 0):

How about This equation: $1+x+2y$?